# How to derive this gradient with multiple variables?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$g(\beta) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i(X\beta)_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(1 +
    \exp(X\beta)_i)$,
where $(X\beta)_i$ means the $i$th row in $X\beta$, how do I get the derivative of $\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta}$? $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times1}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$

(Note $i$ is the index for how many samples here)

How am I suppose to write the expression of $\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta}$ in $X$, $\beta$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ be the $i$-th row of $X$, then
$$
\frac{∂}{∂β}f(X_iβ)=f'(X_iβ)X_i
$$
for any differentiable scalar function $f$. Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\log(1+\exp(t))=\frac{\exp(t)}{1+\exp(t)}
$$

Comment: Do I still have to sum it up by $i$?

Comment: @xxx222 Yes, the usual rules for differentiation still apply. Indeed, the above is just an application of the chain rule.

Comment: So my answer is $\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta} = -yX+\sum\frac{X_i\exp X_i\beta}{1+\exp X_i\beta}$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this looks right.